# integration $\int_{0}^{1/8} \frac{4}{\sqrt{(1-4x^2)}} \,dx$

Tags: integration

integration   equation

$$\int_{0}^{1/8} \frac{4}{\sqrt{(1-4x^2)}} \,dx$$

my work

$t=  \sqrt{(1-4x^2)} $

$dt = -4x/\sqrt{(1-4x^2)} dx $

stuck here also

Answer (score 2):

Use the substitution  $2x=\sin \theta$. Then $\frac{d}{d\theta}x=\frac{1}{2}\cos \theta $ and the integral becomes
$$\int_{0}^{1/8} \frac{4}{\sqrt{(1-4x^2)}} \,dx = \int_{0}^{\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)} 2\,d\theta$$

Answer (score 2):

You can use integration by substitution $ 2x=sin(u) $. Then $ \frac{d}{du}x=\frac{1}{2}\cos(u) $.

We can  rearrange our substitution equation  $ 2x=sin(u) $ into $ u = arcsin(2x) $. So we can find our limits with respect to u. When $ x = \frac{1}{8} \: \: u = arcsin(2\frac{1}{8}) = arcsin(\frac{1}{4}) $ and when $ x = 0  \: \: u = arcsin(0) = 0 $.
So

$ \int_{0}^{1/8} \frac{4}{\sqrt{(1-4x^2)}} \,dx = \int_{0}^{\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)} 2\,du = 2\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) = 0.50536051 $

Comment: Upvoted. Maybe you could add a clarification on why the new integration limits are $0$ and $\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$, because it might not be clear for the asker.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=4x \Rightarrow du=4dx$

> Therefore $\int\frac{4}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}dx=8\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-u^2}}=8\arcsin(2x)+C$

$\Rightarrow\int_{0}^{1/8}\frac{4}{\sqrt{(1-4x^2)}}dx=8\arcsin(\frac{1}{4})$